# Getting error when i added a watermark in a video

Tags: ios

I am creating an application which deals with the video which is exist in local directory of app.Now I want to add a watermark in it. But it is showing an error : -

> {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The
>   media data could not be decoded. It may be damaged.}

Please help me for getting this issue

```
-(void)displayWatermarkInVideo
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Video_20160102191557356_by_videoshow" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVURLAsset *videoAssets = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:URL options:nil];
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAssets tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAssets.duration)
                               ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAssets tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];
//Add image
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame-1.png"];
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(5, 25, 57, 57); //Needed for proper display. We are using the app icon (57x57). If you use 0,0 you will not see it
aLayer.opacity = 0.65; //Feel free to alter the alpha here
//Add text instead of image
CGSize videoSize = [videoAssets naturalSize];
CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
titleLayer.string = @"Text goes here";
titleLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain(@"Helvetica");
titleLayer.fontSize = videoSize.height / 6;
//?? titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
//Sorts the layer in proper order
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:titleLayer]; //ONLY IF WE ADDED TEXT
//Create composition
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
//Create instruction


AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);

AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];
//Export

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/utput_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
exportSession.videoComposition=videoComp;

exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status)
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Export OK");
            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath)) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            }
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportSession.error);
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
            break;
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to generate video with watermark.

```
- (void)videoOutput{// 1 - Early exit if there's no video file selected
if (!self.videoAsset) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Load a Video Asset First"
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

// 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

// 3 - Video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration)
                    ofTrack:[[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration);

// 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:self.videoAsset.duration];

// 3.3 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

float renderWidth, renderHeight;
renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

NSLog(@"naturalSize %f %f", naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);

// no-op - override this method in the subclass
// 1 - Set up the text layer
CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:20];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, 100)];
[subtitle1Text setString:@"Your Text.."];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

// 2 - The usual overlay
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

// 4 - Get path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

// 5 - Create exporter
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                  presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
    NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (error) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                } else {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
            });
        }];
    }
}

    });
}];}
```

Try this code. It perfectly worked for me. Hope this will work for you too.

Comment: I am not getting any error by using your code but my video file is still not playing in document directory after adding watermark.and the function exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler not being called.@Monika

Comment: Its an Asynchronous method so you have to wait until the process has been completed. You will get an alert when the video has been saved. @NehaPurwar

Comment: actually i am getting AVAssetExportSessionFailed. can you tell me what i am doing wrong in this code.

Comment: I tried your code. Just copied. I am getting AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted.

Comment: Do you add some other logic? @Monika

Comment: No nothing. I just pasted your method displayWatermarkInVideo. Added my sample video. And called this method on button action. Are you trying same video everytime? Take one small sample video and try. @NehaPurwar